# Why does it take me a lot more time to traverse the vector than the set when I submit the answer to question 128 of leetcode?

Tags: c++, stl

When I modify the range at the comment and the object traversed by the for loop is nums, the traversal time will be longer. But I checked the relevant information. Generally, isn't the traversal performance of vector better? After all, it's a sequential container.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int longestConsecutive(vector<int>& nums) {
        int max = 0, tmpmax = 0, next = 0;
        unordered_set<int> nums_set;
        for(auto& value: nums)
            nums_set.emplace(value);

        for(auto& value: nums_set){ // is here
            if(nums_set.count(value-1) == 0){
                next = value+1;
                tmpmax = 1;
                while(nums_set.count(next) != 0){
                    tmpmax++;
                    next++;
                }
                if(max < tmpmax)
                    max = tmpmax;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
};
```

Submit records:

- Traversal set:80ms
- Traversal vector:508ms

Comment: Please include the exact compilation commands being used on the platform.

Comment: If `nums` has a lot of repeated values, `nums_set` would be smaller as it only contains unique values. In the limit, if `nums` contains a million copies of the same number, a loop over `num` would run a million iterations while a loop over `nums_set` would only run once.

Comment: @cigien I submitted it directly in the code running area on the right side of leetcode. So I'm sorry I don't know its compilation command.